# What are all possible actions by automorphism of $H = \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ on $N = \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

So the question is "What are all possible actions by automorphism of H on N?" with H = Z/3Z and N = Z/6Z.

I completely guessed my way through how to go about solving this, but I started with finding Aut(Z/6Z) which is {[1],[5]}, and figured that it Aut(Z/6Z) must be isomorphic to Z/2Z.  Working through I found that the only possible action is the direct action Z6 x Z/3Z.

This is most likely wrong, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait..."*automorphisms* of [group] on [a non-isomorphic group]"? I suspect that you may be using the term [automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) in a non-standard way. Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe he means a homomorphism from $H\to Aut(N)$, as for a semidirect product?

Comment: Sorry!  I meant to say "actions by automorphism"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've computed, the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is of order $2$. An action of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ thus arises from a homomorphism from a group of order 3 into a group of order 2, and any such homomorphism is trivial. Thus there is only the trivial action.

Comment: My answer is correct?  Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: @JamesNorton You're welcome.